# How to set text for type datePicker

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, settext

I am doing a setText for a TableView and I have

```
 void handleTableClick (MouseEvent event){
        Donation d = donationTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); 
        if (d != null) {
            donationFirstName.setText(d.getFirstName());
            donationLastName.setText(d.getLastName());
            donationAddress.setText(d.getAddress());
            donationState.setText(d.getState()); 
            donationZipcode.setText(String.valueOf(d.getZipcode()));
            donationDate.setText(d.getDate());
            donationAmount.setText(String.valueOf(d.getAmount()));            
        }
    }
```

I keep getting errors for setText(d.getDate()) since I can't use setText for datePicker so what can i use to accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you leave out the error message/stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaDoc for DatePicker states:

> "The value property represents the currently selected **LocalDate**. An initial date can be set via the constructor or by calling setValue(). The default value is null."

For example

```
DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
int year = 2012;
int month = 5;
int dayOfMonth = 7;
datePicker.setValue(LocalDate.of(year, month, dayOfMonth));
```